# How to use for i loop in search pattern in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to count strings containing a number at the end in a large data file, and for this use the "for i loop" to search all of them consecutively. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=2; i<=253; i++ ))
do
awk -F "\t" '$3 ~ /^names.i$/ {++c} END {print c}' myfile >> output.txt
done
```

For some reason although using awk only gives the right output, the script produces just empty spaces in shell. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the whole thing in 1 awk invocation:

```
awk -F '\t' '
{ split($3,arr,/\./); ++c[arr[2]] }
END { for (i=2;i <= 253;i++) print c[i]+0 }
' myfile > output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ed, I have been trying to do this all day, it works like a charm! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use shell variable `i` directly in awk like that. Pass it to awk first:

```
for (( i=2; i<=253; i++ ))
do
   awk -v i=$i -F "\t" '$3 ~ "^names\." i "$" {++c} END {print c}' myfile >> output.txt
done
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, although gives a warning and prints empty spaces instead of zeroes, so I will go with Ed Morton's answer.

Comment: The warning will be because you need to double-escape characters when using strings to contain REs since string literals get parsed twice, once when the script is read and then again when it executes so you need `\\.` instead of `\.`. The spaces are because you need to use `print c+0` or `printf "%d\n", c` if you want to get a number instead of the null string output when `c` is unset.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, now I know what I (and others) did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
awk -F "\t" '{for (i=2;i<=253;i++) if ($3 ~ /^names.i$/) ++c} END {print c}' myfile
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this too, but for some reason it just gives empty output :(

Comment: You can't include a variable (`i`) in a literal regexp (`/^names.i$/`) - it's treated as the character `i` just like every other letter in that RE.